# Delete rows from one data set which are present in another data set

Tags: r, dplyr

I tried:

```
Final <- OriginalNew[!(OriginalNew$Email %in% Reports$Email),]
```

It gives me an error:

> $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors.

Then I tried:

```
Final <- OriginalNew[!(OriginalNew[["Email"]] %in% Reports[["Email"]]),]
```

and

`Final <- OriginalNew[!(getElement(OriginalNew, "Email") %in% getElement(Reports, "Email")),]`

Both of these give me an error:

> subscript out of bounds

Comment: any chance we can see OriginalNew and Reports data sets?

Comment: OriginalNew and Reports are data sets which have just one column that is of Email. I want OriginalNew to be free of the rows which are present in the Reports.

Comment: Is there any predefined function in r which I can use for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user2673238 your solution looks good. But, I solved the problem using `anti_join` from `dplyr`.

```
final <- dplyr::anti_join(OriginalNew, Reports, by = "Email")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second solution looks fine

```
df1 <- data.frame(email=c("some1@mail.com","some2@mail.com")) #some1@email.com is the duplicate
df2 <- data.frame(email=c("some1@mail.com","some3@mail.com"))

final<-df1[!(df1$email %in% df2$email),]

> final
[1] some2@mail.com
```

I think theres something up with your data

Comment: I tried this, It's giving me an error of $ is valid for atomic vectors.

Comment: try: `final<-df1[!(df1[,'email'] %in% df2[,'email']),]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `merge`.

Example:

```
a<-data.frame(1:50)
names(a) <- c("id")

b<-data.frame(1:20)
names(b)<- c("id")
b$fk<-31:50

merge(a,b,by.x=c("id"), by.y=c("fk"))
```

Comment: I don't know which are the rows from one data set there in another data set also. As the data sets are having thousands of rows.